# Error 500 on Google App Engine out of nothing

Tags: google-app-engine

I got Error 500 on Google App Engine out nothing.

http://oladic.appspot.com/ - this got error.

The same code runs flawlessly at:
http://blogthere.appspot.com/
and 
http://912.latest.oladic.appspot.com/

How could this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been resolved. The post on the downtime-notify list is here:

http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-downtime-notify/browse_thread/thread/7fb8a39149de3b55

The update on the system status page is here:

http://code.google.com/status/appengine/detail/datastore/2010/02/02#ae-trust-detail-datastore-get-latency

Answer (score 1):

You can see the [System Status](http://code.google.com/status/appengine) and check if the error was when the system had problems

Comment: The system status reported that everything was fine, even though multiple people were having this problem, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem for 2 days, turns out it because I'm not listed on Google's "Trusted Developers List?" My only issue now is why Google doesn't return a meaningful error message..

Here's their own thread on the matter. See for yourself.
http://code.google.com/appengine/forum/go-forum.html?place=topic/google-appengine-go/zdMysT6yO30

Answer (score 0):

App Engine appears to be borked this morning, lots of people are having this problem on the [mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/topics) as well.

Comment: I was not aware of that. Seems a system wide issue? That drops my positive bias towards Google App Engine. Thanks for noting.

Answer (score 0):

My [site](http://www.inkjetgarden.com) has just, somewhat unexpectedly, come back online, with no work done by myself.

I assume it was a temporary problem with the App Engine, and, with any luck, your site should come back up soon.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem appeared when I decided to deploy the application. After inquire for a while, I figured out that the problem was being caused due the imports of simplejson (in MacOS) or json (in Windows).

The solution to this, is to import the libraries from django. In my case I did:

```
from django.utils import simplejson
```

I hope this solution will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and like Harph above i eventually realized that the use of a JSON module via the following import:

import json

was the cause of the error (at the Engine side) -something that was not problematic at the development server

I corrected this to

from django.utils import simplejson

And this has solved the problem.

thanks Harph for the tip.

Note: Another very important thing that I'd overlooked, that might actually make it harder for other devs working with the GAE for the first time, is not using the Error Logs in the Admin Console (at the datastore admin interface). This is i believe the surest way to quickly pin down the cause of problems at the GAE side (especially ones you don't see at the development server).